# How to get url Google Page rank with c#

Tags: c#, url, get, pagerank

I am using the code below but it is giving time out error. Though my IP is not blocked and i am able to check via firefox addon searchstatus. The code below i am using seems like outdated and not decent. So my question is how can i get url page rank with c# 4.0

```
        private const UInt32 GOOGLE_MAGIC = 0xE6359A60;

    private static void _mix(ref UInt32 a, ref UInt32 b, ref UInt32 c)
    {
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 13;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 8;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 13;
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 12;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 16;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 5;
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 3;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 10;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 15;
    }

    public static string GoogleCH(string url)
    {
        url = string.Format("info:{0}", url);

        int length = url.Length;

        UInt32 a, b;
        UInt32 c = GOOGLE_MAGIC;

        int k = 0;
        int len = length;

        a = b = 0x9E3779B9;

        while (len >= 12)
        {
            a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) + (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24));
            b += (UInt32)(url[k + 4] + (url[k + 5] << 8) + (url[k + 6] << 16) + (url[k + 7] << 24));
            c += (UInt32)(url[k + 8] + (url[k + 9] << 8) + (url[k + 10] << 16) + (url[k + 11] << 24));
            _mix(ref a, ref b, ref c);
            k += 12;
            len -= 12;
        }
        c += (UInt32)length;
        switch (len)  /* all the case statements fall through */
        {
            case 11:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 10] << 24);
                goto case 10;
            case 10:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 9] << 16);
                goto case 9;
            case 9:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 8] << 8);
                goto case 8;
            /* the first byte of c is reserved for the length */
            case 8:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 7] << 24);
                goto case 7;
            case 7:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 6] << 16);
                goto case 6;
            case 6:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 5] << 8);
                goto case 5;
            case 5:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 4]);
                goto case 4;
            case 4:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 3] << 24);
                goto case 3;
            case 3:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 2] << 16);
                goto case 2;
            case 2:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 1] << 8);
                goto case 1;
            case 1:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            /* case 0: nothing left to add */
        }

        _mix(ref a, ref b, ref c);

        return string.Format("6{0}", c);
    }

    public string getGooglePR(string url)
    {
        Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
        string srUrl = myUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        string checksum = GoogleCH(srUrl);
        string query = string.Format("http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&ch={0}&features=Rank&q=info:{1}", checksum, srUrl);

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(query);
            string response = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            if (response.Length == 0)
                return "01";
            else
                return int.Parse(Regex.Match(response, "Rank_1:[0-9]:([0-9]+)").Groups[1].Value).ToString() + "0";
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            return E.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

c# 4.0

notice : the problem occurs when there are special characters in the url like **&**

Comment: You might consider running fiddler to see what the exact query is being sent by firefox

Comment: Chris Lively thanks for answering but i found the error. The error is hashing function. When there are special characters in the url like & it fails. So how can i fix hashing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for the host of the particular website instead of the full url

does the website url host has &?

Comment: how is that going to help. the aim here is getting full url pagerank

Comment: hello, i ran the code you posted, and it was throwing an error. arithmetics error. when i inspected, the code above was not getting the PR, instead it was returning a webpage with `info:domain` in the search box as query, and one result. does the code still works, maybe i can help you debug it